# List all filenames from windows file share using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-sharing, fileshare

Can someone guide me on how to list all filenames in a windows shared folder using python.
Connecting to this network drive requires a username and password.
Which python libraries do I need?

I'm assuming I need something like:

```
import os

files = []
with open(r"\\12.xxx.xx.123\files",'r') as ff:
    # r = root, d = directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            print("element f = " + f)
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

if my path requires a username and password, how can I pass those credentials to get a successful connection. Currently, I am getting permission denied.

Thanks.

Comment: The duplicate addresses opening the share. Listing files is trivial after that (I recommend `os.scandir` for listing a single directory, or `os.walk` for a whole tree); make sure to use raw strings, or your paths will be wrong (e.g. the example path you provided `"\\111.000.1.0\folder1\"` is, thanks to escapes being processed, actually `\111.000.1.0<FORMFEED>older1<SyntaxError because the close quote was escaped>`. You wanted `r"\\111.000.1.0\folder1"` (note leading `r` to make it raw, and lack of trailing backslash, which is unnecessary and causes problems in raw strings).

Comment: thanks for the reply ... do u have examples on how to connect to the file share using username/password .... syntax please...

Comment: That's what you find on the duplicate...

Comment: I'm sorry Shadow .. I dont understand ... what do you mean by the duplicate addresses open the share? When I try to access the file using file explorer it will prompt me for a username and password ... i am assuming those credentials will have to be in the python script to access the files as well.

Comment: I changed my code a bit, I just need to pass those credentials ....username and password .. please look at my code above.

Comment: Read the answers on the duplicate I linked. They explain how you can use either command line tools via the `subprocess` module, or third-party packages, to mount a file share, including logging in with username or password. Please read *all* the answers; they include example code, and they fully answer how you do this.